# Finding a circle in a graph using DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a question,
which algorithm could I use to find a circle in a graph G=(V,E,w).
I know there is a solution by running the improved DFS algorithm on G and then run on every edge and check this condition:

Defining edge like: `e = (x, y)` where `x` point to `y`.

```
if(low[y] <= d[x])
   e is inside a circle
```

I am not quite sure if this is the solution, someone can help me figure this out?

Thank you !

Comment: By "circle" do you mean "cycle"?  If so then it's even simpler: just record in a table whether you have visited each vertex yet or not.  If during DFS you discover an edge (x, y) with y already visited, you have found a cycle.  If the graph is not necessarily connected then you will need to perform this for each connected component.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting cycles in a graph using DFS: 2 different approaches and what's the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113189/detecting-cycles-in-a-graph-using-dfs-2-different-approaches-and-whats-the-dif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the condition you've written.

It is true because if the low[y] value is actually less then or equal to the d[x] value so surely e is an edge on a cycle which accessible from the 'back edge'.

The low[y] value is the d[u] of the minimum d[..] edges that are accessible to y via a back edge.